# How to leave the current app and launch an activity of another app?

Tags: android, android-activity, launch

I have a simple Android app that needs to launch another app under certain condition, and I will need to check the condition upon the app launch. That is, either continue to launch my app or just launch another app:

```
if (A == true) {
 launch another activity of another app
 leave the current app without creating the main activity
} else {
 launch the main activity of the current app
}
```

Could anyone please let me know how to deal with A == true case? I am able to launch another app's activity but I have trouble leaving the current app without even opening the main activity.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just try to add this code before setContentView in your onCreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch other application using following intent

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.abc");//pass the packagename of app you want to open
startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```

If you don't know the package name of application that you wanted to launch then try your hand on

```
PackageManager pm;
pm = getPackageManager();
//  get a list of installed apps.
packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
```

Pass the packagename of app you want to open
You can use this if A == true

else You can launch the MainActivity as

```
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start another activity of another app without the normal [IntentFilter](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#npex) then the easiest solutions is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.anotherapp.package","com.anotherapp.package.MainActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Of course, you would **need to know** the `package name` and the `Activity` name you want to start

As for finishing your application call

```
finishAndRemoveTask();
```

Comment: finishAndRemoveTask() is exactly what i am looking for, thanks!

Comment: Awesome, if this helps don't forget to up vote / accept the answer as per SO guidelines ;). Glad I could help!

Comment: Why did you remove? Wth I thought I had helped you out.